# Emma code coverage for android JUnit test

Tags: android, testing, junit

How to run Eclemma code coverage tool for android Junit test, not for Junit test? Can any one please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to add **ant** build files to both projects (main and test) and then use the specific ant targets to generate the coverage report.
 Then you can import the coverage report to EclEmma.

To add the ant build you first need to disable ***Project -> Build Automatically*** in Eclipse to avoid conflicts.

These steps are described in http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2011/07/eclipse-android-and-emma-code-coverage.html.